# React Native flatlist specific data

Tags: json, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Im requiring data from a local json file just for test purposes (On a ideal world im going to fetch data from a remote url) this json file is an array with 8 objects, but I need the flatlist just to render the first 3, how can I do that?

My code:

```
import extratoData from "./extratoData.json"

export default function Body () {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {setData(extratoData)}, [])

  return(
   <FlatList 
    data={extratoData} 
    renderItem={({item}) => <ExtratoRenderItem title={item.title} amount={item.amount} date={item.date} time={item.time} cashback={item.cashBack}/>}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
   />
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the `Array.prototype.slice()` method.

```
  var firstThree = extratoData.slice(0, 3);
```